# Action is cached in Controller in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

When i try to reach `/controllername/action1`

It finds and runs it, when i add some code into `action1`, browser shows the old action's results.
It seems like function is cached.

But in my `app/tmp/cache` folder there is no file with action's or controller's name.

I tried `Cache::clear()` - But the result is the same.
My debug level is `2`.

How can I fix this problem ?

Comment: is this a hosted site or local ?

Comment: Are you sure it's actually running the action you direct to and it's not routing you to someplace else? If you check the controller file that is supposed to contain the action on your local file system, does the time your OS say it was last edited reflect the actual time it was last edited? (in other words: are you editing the right file and not a copy in a backup directory?)

Comment: Isn't it just cached by your browser ? What happens if you go the same url after having cleared the browser's cache or with another browser ?

Comment: @nlcO i checked with another browser and the old action results came.

Comment: @Joep It doesn't route to somewhere else, i can see the old action's results. I can see that local file is changed. To check i changed very small difference in action. (add one echo to it) But still it showed the same results even i change the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the problem is with my network card.
I solved issue. Thanks.